# Indy 8 to Indy 10 - What replaces TIdLogDebug component?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, indy-8

I have a project that was written in Delphi 6 and used Indy 8.  I need to upgrade this project to Delphi 2005 and use Indy 10.

In Delphi 2005, when I open the Form containing the old Indy components, the following two errors occur:

> Property OnLogItem does not exist
>
> Property Target does not exist

Both of these errors have to do with Indy's `TIdLogDebug` component.

I have heard that instead of using the `TIdLogDebug`, one must use `TIdLogEvent` instead. However, this component does not have the `OnLogItem` and `Target` properties.

What event handler should I use with the `TIdLogEvent` component of Indy 10, that substitutes the `OnLogItem` event of the `TIdLogDebug` component of Indy 8?

Comment: Thanks Ken, I've changed my question and hopefully it is clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdLogDebug` itself still exists in Indy 10, but it is very different than Indy 8's `TIdLogDebug`.  `TIdLogDebug` in Indy 9 and later does not have a `Target` property or an `OnLogItem` event anymore.

Indy 8's `TIdLogDebug` was Indy's only logging component and it supported multiple types of output - file, debugger, and event.  In Indy 9, that functionality was split into separate `TIdLogFile`, `TIdLogDebug`, and `TIdLogEvent` components (and a new `TIdLogStream` component was added).

In Indy 9 and later, the `TIdLogEvent` component would be the correct replacement to use.  `TIdLogEvent` has `OnReceived`, `OnSent`, and `OnStatus` events.  Indy 8 did not differentiate between different directions of data flow in `TIdLogDebug`, everything was funneled through the single `OnLogItem` event.  The log messages for each direction of data flow had different prefixes.  In Indy 9 and later, separate events are now used for each direction, so there is no direct replacement for the old `OnLogItem` event.  You need to update your code to fit in with the newer event model.

Comment: Thanks Remy, that answers my question perfectly.